# Finding the equation of a tangent plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm trying to learn how to compute a tangent plane of a multivariate function. However, it's hard for me to check if I'm correct and I'm interested in knowing where I made a mistake, since I likely did. The function I'm trying to find a tangent plane to is:

$$xz-yz^3+yz=2$$

About the point $ (x_0,y_0,z_0)=(2,-1,1)$

I've never computed a tangent plane with $3$ inputs, but I assume it's the same concept just extended to a new input. Resultatively, my first assumption here is that this is a function with inputs $(x,y,z)$ and thus have a plane of this general form:

$$L(x,y,z) = a(x-x_0) + b(y-y_0) + c(z-z_0)+w_0$$

Now, I think my next assumption is where my mistake lies but I'm not sure what else to do: I need to find $w_0$ and this is going to be $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

Thus, I have the following:

$$w = xz-yz^3+yz-2$$

Plugging in the point $(2,-1,1)$ renders:

$$2+1-1-2 = 0$$
$$w_0 = 0$$

So I now have:

$$L(x,y,z) = a(x-x_0) + b(y-y_0) + c(z-z_0)+w_0$$

Now I just need the partial derivatives to find $a$, $b$, and $c$.

$$a = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (2,-1,1) = z$$
$$a = 1$$

$$b = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (2,-1,1) = z-z^3$$
$$b = 0$$

$$c = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} (2,-1,1) = x-3yz^2+y$$
$$c = 4$$

Finally, my tangent plane equation is:

$$L(x,y,z) = (x-2) + 4(z-1) $$

I'm skeptical about this answer because there's no $y$ input and I feel my construction of $w = xz-yz^3+yz-2$ was incorrect. Please explain to me my mistake in the likely case that there is one.

Comment: I think there is a short cut where you can just calculate the gradient at the point and the tangent plane will be orthogonal to it. Partial derivative to y is 0 at the point and you know the relation between normal to plane and plane equation.

Comment: Getting picky about terminology, the expression you’ve written down at the top is not a function, although it does define a surface that’s a level set of the function $f:(x,y,z)\mapsto xz-yz^3+yz$. On the other hand, $L(x,y,z)=\dots$ isn’t an equation of a plane, but is just the definition of a function of three variables. That aside, your calculations are correct. Not having a $y$ term just means that the plane is parallel to the $y$-axis.